# What do the characters ((?:(?:(?: mean in pattern-matching?

Tags: java, regex

I have some code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

private boolean validateEmail(...)

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^((?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][\\.\\-\\+_]?)*)[a-zA-Z0-9])+)\\@((?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][\\.\\-_]?){0,62})[a-zA-Z0-9])+)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6})$");

Matcher m = p.matcher(fieldValue);
boolean matches = m.matches();

if (!matches) {    
// show not valid msg...
}
return matches;
}
```

What do `^((?:(?:(?:` and `((?:(?:(?:` mean in that pattern?
The `^` character mean negation (all without) but other characters?

Comment: What does [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) tell you they mean?

Comment: Here are couple java regex tutorial to get u started with : http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: They are smiles - this is the way how regex shows it's sympathy to you.

Comment: More explicitly, they are sarcastic smiles.

Answer (score 3):

`(?:...)` denotes a non capturing group. `?:` is used when you want to group an expression,   but you want to avoid to return it as a matched/captured portion of the string.

The `^` does not mean negation when it is located outside square breackets. It means match from the beginning of the string.